# Navigating to another activity using databinding in mvvp structure

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am learning data binding library and I am totally new to this. My question is how to navigate to another activity on data binding.

Can I do it just like we do it in MVC or I have to put that code in ViewModel. Please help me.

Here is my code.

**Activity:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initDataBinding();
    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {
    findViewById(R.id.guest_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,GameActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

private void initDataBinding() {
    ActivitySplashBinding activitySplashBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_splash);
    SplashViewModel splashViewModel = new SplashViewModel();
    activitySplashBinding.setSplashViewModel(splashViewModel);
    splashViewModel.addObserver(this);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {

}
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.sevenbits.android.mvvmsample.view.SplashActivity">

<data>
    <variable name="splashViewModel"
              type="com.sevenbits.android.mvvmsample.viewmodel.SplashViewModel"/>

</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/parent1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/parent1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.42"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/parent1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/parent1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.58"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/guest_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="Play As a Guest User"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Do I need to put onclick code in view model? If yes, then How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that really depends on the use case but ideally every action should go through ViewModel.

If you need to do some stuff before navigation like storing the data, your click action should go from ViewModel. If you just need to redirect, you can do it MVC way.

I generally do it in this way:

SplashViewModel.java

```
public static final int ACTION_NAVIGATE_TO_GAME = 1000;

public void navigateToGame() {
    // You can do some work here before notifying the view about redirection
    setChanged();
    notifyObserver(ACTION_NAVIGATE_TO_GAME);
}
```

SplashActivity.java

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
    if (data instanceof Integer) {
        int value = (int) data;
        switch(value) {
           case SplashViewModel.ACTION_NAVIGATE_TO_GAME:
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,GameActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and in layout file

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/guest_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="Play As a Guest User"
            android:onClick="@{() -> splashViewModel.navigateToGame()}"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
```

Comment: Thank You for your help.